# Optimization where solutions only need to fall below a threshold?

Tags: optimization, programming

I am interested in a particular type of optimization problem, which seems relevant to engineering applications, in particular. Suppose that I don't need a function to be fully optimized -- I can consider the problem solved when I have found any solution $x^*\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x^*)<T$ for some target threshold $T\in\mathbb{R}$.

Furthermore, consider that my primary concern is the cost of computing functional values during each iteration $i$ -- e.g. because I must run a manual experiment or cumbersome simulation in order to determine $f(x_i)$. In such a case, is there an efficient approach to solving this problem, other than simply relying on algorithms that attempt to minimize function evaluations?

Has anyone heard of such a thing?

Comment: Without knowing more about the nature of the function at hand, it may not even be possible to use an algorithm to find the minimum (since smooth, mostly convex functions are generally used in optimization problems such as the one you are describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a feasibility problem, which is a special case of optimization problem.

Include the target objective value as a constraint, $f(x^*) \le T$,  in addition to all the other constraints. If the optimization software allows, submit that to the solver without any objective function, or if need be, include a constant objective function, such as minimize 0.